# Align :=, =, and =: symbols

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, mathtools

What is the best way to get the symbols `\coloneq`, `=`, and `\eqcolon` (provided by package `mathtools`) to align in a nice way (so the equals part of each is aligned) in an align environment?

I can get the first two to align nicely by putting the `&` afterward and using an empty field to get the mathrel alignment right, as follows, ...but the third is badly aligned.

```tex
r(x) \coloneq{}& \log x^{-(k+1)} + k\\
            ={}& -\log x \quad\text{if } k=0\\
     \eqcolon{}& s(x)
```

[image]

Likewise, if I left-align them, the second two are well-aligned, but the firstone isn't:

```tex
r(x) &\coloneq \log x^{-(k+1)} + k\\
     &= -\log x \quad\text{if } k=0\\
     &\eqcolon s(x)
```

[image]

I suppose I could nudge things around with some ad hoc adjustments, but, is there a better way fix this?

Comment: I think you mean `\coloneqq`?

Comment: actually no, I mean `\coloneq`.  Though they're the same thing, of course. According to the [mathtools docs](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf), as of 2022, the one-q version is the default macro for that symbol. Though the name \coloneqq is still supported as a "Legacy duplicate name".  Likewise for \eqcolon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the symbols for alignment with suitable phantoms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\phantomcolon}{\mathrel{\phantom{:\mkern-1.2mu}}}

\newcommand{\acoloneqq}{\coloneqq\phantomcolon}
\newcommand{\aeqqcolon}{\phantomcolon\eqqcolon}
\newcommand{\aequalsa}{\phantomcolon=\phantomcolon}
\newcommand{\aequals}{\phantomcolon=}
\newcommand{\equalsa}{=\phantomcolon}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
r(x) &\acoloneqq \log x^{-(k+1)} + k\\
     &\aequalsa  -\log x \quad\text{if } k=0\\
     &\aeqqcolon s(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\aequalsa` when both kinds of colons are used, `\aequals` for colons only on the left or `\equalsa` for colons only on the right. In the last two cases, you will just use `\eqqcolon` or `\coloneqq`.

Or just forget about the colons and use = as mathematicians did for a few centuries before programming languages advertised colons.

Comment: +1 for "Or just forget about the colons and use = as mathematicians did for a few centuries before programming languages advertised colons".

Comment: For pedagogical reasons, this can be useful with young students...

Comment: @projetmbc I fully disagree. But it's a matter of opinions.

Comment: @egreg Newer forget the polysemy of the symbol `=` from the beginner point of view.

Comment: @projetmbc It's the second topic of my lectures in Mathematics Teaching; next Monday, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, that works; I suppose I can't picture anything less hacky, anyway. It's not a common thing to need.  And yeah, I take the point about it not being necessary.  I feel that sometimes these kind of additional diacritics help communication.